# iOS Application crash after launch screen

Tags: ios, swift

I have converted app coded in Swift 2.1 to Swift 4.1, and almost all build related issue solved and now when I am going to run it its giving me error as below.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unable to instantiate the UIApplication subclass instance. No class named Application is loaded.'

*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ff471e6 __exceptionPreprocess + 294
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f5dc031 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ff4c472 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010a75464f -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] + 165
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010aca0306 _UIApplicationMainPreparations + 629
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010aca0027 UIApplicationMain + 111
    6   DeÃÅplacement PeÃÅninsule           0x0000000108486271 main + 401
    7   libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000114618955 start + 1
    8   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Actually I have already check, that its using correct Info.plist.

Comment: Check [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Unable+to+instantiate+the+UIApplication+subclass+instance).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23814648/unable-to-instantiate-the-uiapplication-subclass-instance

Comment: If are not able to track the crash with symbolic break point. then you need to symbolicate the crash report.

Comment: Do you actually have a class named `Application`?

Comment: @ManishMahajan Thanks for reply, but I have already check path, and it all okay.

Comment: @user1118321 No I don't have.

Comment: @PrabhatPankaj can you please give me some hint for symbolicate the crash report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying that it can't find any object of the principal class to instantiate when starting the app. The `Principal class` entry in the Info.plist file tells the `UIApplicationMain()` function which class to load on startup.  You can try changing that entry to `UIApplication`, or creating a subclass of `UIApplication` named `Application` to fix this.

Comment: Thanks, actually I just removed NSPrincipalClass entry from list, as I check if I create new project in Xcode 9 with swift 4, there is no such entry, so I removed and now its working. Your answer leads me to check that. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Symbolication of crash report

1)Copy symbolicatecrash from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/ SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ symbolicatecrash 
to new folder "crashreport"

2)Goto "crashreoprt" folder

3)Symbolicate using command

Note:

1)Build should be release.

2)Strip debug symbols during copy should be "NO"

3)crashreport folder must have (Symbolicationcrash,.crash
and .app)

Answer (score -2):

Symbolication of crash report
1)Copy symbolicatecrash from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/ SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ symbolicatecrash to new folder "crashreport"
2)Goto "crashreoprt" folder
3)Symbolicate using command
Note:
1)Build should be release.
2)Strip debug symbols during copy should be "NO"
3)crashreport folder must have (Symbolicationcrash,.crash
and .app)